# Showing differentiability of smoothed function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, possibly non-differentiable.

We define the smoothed function $$\hat{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{B}}[f(\mathbf{x}+\delta \mathbf{v})],$$ where the expectation is taken over the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, we average the function $f$ around a $\delta$-radius ball to get the smoothed function $\hat f$.

How can I show $\hat f(\mathbf{x})$ is differentiable? I'm stuck after writing the basic expression to show it is differentiable!

$$ \mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}+\delta \mathbf{v})] \overset?=  \mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{x}+\delta \mathbf{v})] + \mathbf{h}^T\nabla \mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{x}+\delta \mathbf{v})] + o(\| \mathbf{h} \|)$$

Comment: TeX note:  the "might be equal" `=?=` spaces very poorly:  $a =?= b$.  I suggested an edit to replace it by `\overset?=` $a \overset?= b$, but it was rejected.  Another option is to give TeX more explicit instructions about how you mean `=?=` to be parsed, using `\mathbin{{=}?{=}}`:  $a \mathbin{{=}?{=}} b$.

Comment: @LSpice Duly noted and fixed.